# Do types of stripes have specific terms?

Tags: word-request

Are there specific words to describe **horizontal or vertical stripes** (esp. in clothes)?

For example, when I go shopping and I want a shirt with vertical stripes, what should I say?

"I am looking for horizontally striped shirts"?!

Also, I've heard Americans refer to their flags as **stars and stripes**. Does this mean when "stripes" is used, by default it's considered horizontal?

Comment: There are no specific words to describe horizontal or vertical strips. The only descriptive *stripe* word I can think of is pinstripe http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pinstripe?s=t

Comment: No, **stripes** is not by default assumed to be horizontal. // The only named stripe-like pattern (besides the pinstripe @Chris mentioned) I can think of is a chevron (the upside-down "v"s stacked on top of each other).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no specific terms for the orientation of stripes. You just have to ask for the orientation that you want (or wish to avoid): vertical, horizontal or diagonal. Sometimes, there is no choice: I have yet to see men's formal shirts with anything other than vertical stripes.

For an example of current usage, see: [The Telegraph: Are stripes flattering?](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/fashion/style/are-stripes-flattering/)